# HowlerJS - Audio player - Error 401 (unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, angular, html, html5-audio, howler.js

so am working with **Angular 7** and i've created an app that consume from an api, i did create an http-interceptor and all my crud functionalities work fine, the http interceptor technically add a token on each request.
so the problem that am having is when i have added HowlerJs i got 401 error and i have looked into that and i could not found a solution for that.
here is my code:

```
public play_audio_file(id: string) {
    this.httpClient.get(`${this.Url}/${id}/audiofile`, {
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: {
           'Accept': 'audio/*',
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
        }
   }) 
.subscribe(blob => {
    var sound = new Howl({
        src: `${this.Url}/${id}/audiofile`, 
        format: ['wav'],
    });

    sound.play();
    console.log(sound)
});
}
```

please note that its not necessary for me to work with howler, all am trying to do is to play the audio, even with an HTML audio player, 
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So, i was WRONG ... all the way wrong, and i have find a solution,
i did get 401 because i do 2 calls one from httpclient and from howlerJS, the one from httpclient has token ,  but the second has no token and thus lead to an error -401-
so i have change my code to the following :

```
        public play_audio_file(id: string) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = `${this.Url}/${id}/audiofile`;
                xhr.open('GET', encodeURI(url), true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token`);
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.onload = function (evt) {
                    var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'audio/*' });
                    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    var sound = new Howl({
                        src: objectUrl, 
                        format: ['wav'],
                    }); 
                    sound.play();
                //OR with web audio API
                    // var audio = new Audio();
                    // audio.src = objectUrl; 
                    // audio.onload = function (evt) {
                    //  URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
                    // };
                    // audio.play();
                };
        xhr.send(); 
    }
```

Or even better with HttpClient :

```
public play_audio_file(id: string) {
        this.httpClient.get(`${this.Url}/${id}/audiofile`, { responseType: "blob", headers: { 'Accept': 'audio/*' } })
            .subscribe(blob => {
                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
                var sound = new Howl({
                        src: objectUrl, 
                        format: ['wav'],
                    }); 
                    sound.play();
                //OR with web audio API
                    // var audio = new Audio();
                    // audio.src = objectUrl; 
                    // audio.onload = function (evt) {
                    //  URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
                    // };
                    // audio.play();
            });
}
```